# Compare two dates in sql query giving error - Codeigniter Query Builder

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter-3

Here is my code:

```
function get_late_jobs($date1, $date2) {
    $this->db->select('Delivery.Packlist, Delivery.Job, Delivery.Promised_Date, Delivery.Shipped_Date, Job.Customer');
    $this->db->join('Job', 'Delivery.Job = Job.Job', 'inner');
    $this->db->where('Delivery.Promised_Date <', 'Delivery.Shipped_Date');
    $this->db->where('Delivery.Job IS NOT NULL', NULL);
    $this->db->where('Delivery.Shipped_Date IS NOT NULL', NULL);
    $this->db->where('Delivery.Shipped_Date >=', $date1);
    $this->db->where('Delivery.Shipped_Date <=', $date2);
    $this->db->order_by('Delivery.Shipped_Date');
    $query = $this->db->get( 'Delivery' );
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

I keep getting this error:

Error Number: 22007/241

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

```
SELECT 
  "Delivery"."Packlist", 
  "Delivery"."Job", 
  "Delivery"."Promised_Date", 
  "Delivery"."Shipped_Date", 
  "Job"."Customer" 
FROM "Delivery" 
INNER JOIN "Job" 
  ON "Delivery"."Job" = "Job"."Job" 
WHERE 
  "Delivery"."Promised_Date" < 'Delivery.Shipped_Date' 
  AND "Delivery"."Job" IS NOT NULL 
  AND "Delivery"."Shipped_Date" IS NOT NULL 
  AND "Delivery"."Shipped_Date" >= '2018-08-08' 
  AND "Delivery"."Shipped_Date" <= '2018-08-15' 
ORDER BY 
  "Delivery"."Shipped_Date"
```

Filename: C:/inetpub/wwwroot/portalci/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

I have already tested the query in SQL Management Studio and the query is an exact copy from an old procedural php page that exist.

Comment: If I comment out the line:
$this->db->where('Delivery.Promised_Date <', 'Delivery.Shipped_Date');
it works

Comment: It looks like your column `Promised_Date` is not stored as a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest replacing

```
'Delivery.Shipped_Date'
```

with

```
"Delivery"."Shipped_Date"
```

The former is a string constant which cannot be converted to a date.

Comment: Was this helpful at all?